# Typescript context API issues state not changing

Tags: typescript

```
  type IContextGlobalProps = {
    globalstate: GlobalProps,

    updateGlobalState?: (id: any) => void 
  }

  const initialGlobalState = {
    globalstate:{
    hotelID: "",
    userData: {},
    dashboardData: {},
    locationID: "-1",
    isUserTranslating: false,
    alarms: { private: [], global: [], isGlobalModalOpen: false },
    calendarDateFrom: "",
    calendarDateTo: "",
    browser_session_id: 0,
    instantMessages: [],
    recentMessages: [],
    chatUserList: [],
    websocket: undefined,
    unreadMessageCount: 0,
    searchText: "",
    dashboard_: false,
    chatStatus: "disable",
    searchDropdown: "",
    propertySettingsURL: "",
    defaultLayoutLoaded: false,
    recentlyChattedUserID: "-2",
    sidebarShow: true, //comes with coreui
    sidebarUnfoldable: true, //comes with coreui
    asideShow: false, //comes with coreui
    theme: 'default', //comes with coreui
  },
  // setGlobalState: () => {}

  }

export const GlobalStore = createContext<IContextGlobalProps>(initialGlobalState);
export const DashboardStore = createContext<IContextDashboardProps>(initialDashboardState);


const Store = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [globalstate, setGlobalState] = useState<GlobalProps>({...initialGlobalState.globalstate});
    const [dashboardstate, setDashboardState] = useState(initialDashboardState);
    
  

    const updateGlobalState = (id:any) => {
      const clone = {...globalstate};
      clone.hotelID = id
      setGlobalState(clone)
    };    

    return (      
        <GlobalStore.Provider value={{globalstate,updateGlobalState}}>
 
                {children}                
 
        </GlobalStore.Provider>
    );
};

other component 
  const {globalstate, updateGlobalState} = useContext(GlobalStore)

   const SetPropertyID = (id: any) => {
    updateGlobalState(id)
  }
```

Error i am getting

```
 Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
    75 |
    76 |     // console.log("SetPropertyID: ", id)
  > 77 |     updateGlobalState(id)
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    78 |
    79 |   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your type `IContextGlobalProps`, the property is `updateGlobalState` is defined as [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties), which means the prop `updateGlobalState` may or may not exist on the returned context.

1. If there is a case when `updateGlobalState` may be `undefined`, then use [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to call the method. Like- `updateGlobalState?.(id)`
2. If you are sure that `updateGlobalState` will never be `undefined` then remove `?` from `IContextGlobalProps`. Like-

```
type IContextGlobalProps = {
    globalstate: GlobalProps,

    updateGlobalState: (id: any) => void
    // ------------- ^ ? removed here
 }
```

3. As mentioned by @kellys in the comment, if you are sure that `updateGlobalState` will never be `undefined` for your said component, then use [Non null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-)

Comment: And if it's never `undefined` **only for this component** you use `updateGlobalState!()` with `!` to assert that it is non-nullable.